# Scale up and scale down of azure app service plan (Based on non-business hours) using azure automation script

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have to Scale up and scale down of azure app service plan (Based on non-business hours) using azure automation service.

I have visited lot of websites but everywhere it is about scale out or increasing/decreasing the instance count.

But my requirement is I want to change app service plan from S2 to S1 and vice versa based on timings.

Please help me....

Comment: Just be aware that changing the service plan, vs scaling the number of instances, will also directly impact the amount of RAM and storage you have. For S-tier to S-tier, you won't lose storage, but the amount of RAM changes, which could be an issue depending on your app's needs.

Comment: Just create two runbooks, use `Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan`, one to scale from S1 to S2, another one scale from S2 to S1, set the Schedule with starting at 9:00 AM, Recur every one day and starting at 9:00 PM, also Recur every one day. Could it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 4):

this is what you are looking for:

```
Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ServicePlanName -Location $WebAppLocation -Tier Standard -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "Small"
```

workerSize can be small, medium, large, extralarge

Comment: I am looking for the code snippet to execute above code based on time(Scheduled)  so that i can run it withing runbook.

Comment: you dont need a code snippet, runbook can be run on a schedule

Comment: But i need to write this conditionally ? like if time is between 9:00 AM to 9:00 PM i want to scale at S2 but if its 9:00 PM to 8:59 AM i want to reduce it at S1....

Comment: well, kinda, just create a parameter or infer what you need to do from the current time, its extremely easy either way

Comment: I want some thing like below link :https://jorgklein.com/2017/09/19/azure-sql-database-scheduled-autoscaling/ Instead of SQL i want to do it for app service

Comment: I know ..so just checking if somebody already written or exist the same on  Runbooks Gallery of azure...hope you understand my concern.....thanks fr ur support...

Comment: just mimic that article with this command to scale the app service plan, thats it