# How to start or stop appservices in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I want to stop my appservices at midnight and want to start them at morning.So i came across two things , runbooks and webjobs .So first i included a runbook which start/stop services in a resource group.But when i tested it out , i faced an error -

[image]

And also when i tried using a webjob , i used this [code from here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Stop-or-Start-all-WebApps-9b32ca91) , but i was not able to see the result.The webjob was working as a script but was it actually starting/stoping the services i dont know.I am new to powershell scripts so i dont know where to make necessary changes in the code.I dont know whether i am doing it right or wrong , please help me out.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage Azure ARM Resource with Azure Runbook, you can create `Run As accounts` in your Azure automation account. When we create it, it will create a new service principal user in Azure Active Directory (AD) and assigns the Contributor role to this user at the subscription level. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account#get-permissions-to-configure-run-as-accounts) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-powershell#step-5---add-authentication-to-manage-azure-resources).

For example

1. Create `Run As accounts`

   a. Search for and select **Automation Accounts**.

   b. On the Automation Accounts page, select your Automation account from the list.

   c. In the left pane, select **Run As Accounts** in the account settings section.

   d. Depending on which account you require, select either **Azure Run As Account** or **Azure Classic Run As Account**.

   e. Depending on the account of interest, use the Add **Azure Run As** or Add **Azure Classic Run As Account** pane. After reviewing the overview information, click **Create**.
   [image]
2. [Create a PowerShell Workflow runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual#step-1---create-new-runbook)
3. Script

```
workflow START_STOP_APP_SERVICE_BY_RESOURCE
{
    Param( 
        [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)] 
        [bool]$Stop, 


       [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)] 
        [string]$ResourcegroupName 
    )

    try
    {
        # use Azure As Account to log in Azure
        $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"      

        Add-AzureRmAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
        $status = 'Stopped' 
        if ($Stop) 
        { 
            $status = 'Running' 
        } 

        # Get Running WebApps (website_Processings_Running) 
        $website_Processings_Running = Get-AzureRMWebAPP -ResourceGroupName $ResourcegroupName | where-object -FilterScript{$_.state -eq $status } 

        foreach -parallel ($website_Processing In $website_Processings_Running) 
        { 
            if ($Stop) 
            { 
                $result = Stop-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourcegroupName -Name $website_Processing.Name 
                if($result) 
                { 
                    Write-Output "- $($website_Processing.Name) shutdown successfully" 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    Write-Output "+ $($website_Processing.Name) did not shutdown successfully" 
                } 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $result = Start-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourcegroupName -Name $website_Processing.Name 
                if($result) 
                { 
                    Write-Output "- $($website_Processing.Name) start successfully" 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    Write-Output "+ $($website_Processing.Name) did not started successfully" 
                } 
            }  
        } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: for the script , do i need to make any changes in the code?Thank you for your reply

Comment: @BhaveshDamorb After you do step1, you can directly run my script.

Comment: So i have few doubts - 1)If i am making an automation account , that would cost me extra , right? 2)can i directly upload this code in the webjobs , as webjobs dont have extra cost. 3)how do i schedule them , like stop at midnight and start in the morning?

Comment: @BhaveshDamor Could you please tell me how you stop or restart Azure app service?

Comment: my main objective is to stop app services at a specific time and start them again after some hours to reduce cost.As of now , i only know manually to stop/start app sevice.And i want to automate this task.

Comment: @BhaveshDamor We cannot save on cost by stopping a WebApp because the underlying VM on which the App is hosted is still running : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3df6ccfc-3de1-4c22-ae45-f25aacd647dc/how-to-auto-schedule-web-app-start-stop-service-to-reduce-the-cost?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: i dont have enough points to have a chat with you on stackoverflow.Is there a way to contact you by other means , i have some doubts that i need to clarify.Thank You

Comment: @BhaveshDamor Sorry. I cannot provide my contact information. You can describe your issue here.

Comment: 1)I am working in a azure subscription in which i am just a member , so i was not able to create automation run as account.I requested the higher-ups to build one as they are the head of the subscription.I am not able to see the automation run as account but the higher-ups can see it in their log-in.Will this affect the runbook?

Comment: @BhaveshDamor It will not affect your run book. Once your colleagues create it, you can use it.

Comment: Also if i add the runbook for scaling the service plan up/down to save the cost , will it affect in a negative way?And how to do scaling? i found a way to do it with the help of azure monitor.

Comment: @BhaveshDamor Is that you want to change Azure app service plan instance count . If so, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924187/scale-up-and-scale-down-of-azure-app-service-plan-based-on-non-business-hours

Answer (score 0):

Today in 2022 you have to use Az module instead of AzureRM. You also have to switch to 7.1 Runtime if you want to succeed.

```
Param( 
    [bool]$Stop, 
    [string]$ResourcegroupName,
    [string]$WebAppName 
)
try
{
    # use Azure As Account to log in Azure
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"      

    Write-Output $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId
    Write-Output $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId
    Write-Output $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    Add-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
    $status = 'Stopped' 
    if ($Stop) 
    { 
        $status = 'Running' 
    } 

    # Get Running WebApps (website_Processings_Running) 
    $website_Processings_Running = Get-AzWebApp `
        -ResourceGroupName $ResourcegroupName] `
        -Name $WebAppName | where-object -FilterScript{$_.state -eq $status}

    Write-Output "- $($website_Processing.Name) WebApp to manage" 

    foreach ($website_Processing In $website_Processings_Running) 
    { 
        if ($Stop) 
        { 
            $result = Stop-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourcegroupName -Name $website_Processing.Name
            if($result) 
            { 
                Write-Output "- $($website_Processing.Name) shutdown successfully" 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                Write-Output "+ $($website_Processing.Name) did not shutdown successfully" 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $result = Start-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourcegroupName -Name $website_Processing.Name
            if($result) 
            { 
                Write-Output "- $($website_Processing.Name) start successfully" 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                Write-Output "+ $($website_Processing.Name) did not started successfully" 
            } 
        }  
    }
```